# Office 365 Rest API SendMail errors depending on file attachment extension

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to send an email on the fly with attachments, as outlined here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#SendMessageOnTheFly

Using this JSON body, I receive a 202 response from the server and successfully receive an email with the file attached.

```
Post to https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/sendmail:
{
  Message: {
    Subject: "...", 
    Body: {
      ContentType: "HTML", 
      Content: "..."
    }, 
    ToRecipients: [
      {
        EmailAddress: {
          Address: "..."
        }
      }
    ], 
    Attachments: [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment", 
        Name: "test.txt", 
        ContentBytes: "bWFjIGFuZCBjaGVlc2UgdG9kYXk="
      }
    ]
  }, 
  SaveToSentItems: true
}
```

However, if I change the name to "test.msg" I receive a 500 Internal Server Error with a this response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
        "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
    }
}
```

and with "test.eml", I also receive a 500 Internal Server Error, but with a different response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
        "message": "Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.ItemAttachmentType' to type 'Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.FileAttachmentType'."
    }
}
```

Strangely, for both of those cases, I still receive the email along with the attachment. This is frustrating because currently my application is telling the user that an error occurred sending the email (based on the non-successful status code) but the email was actually sent.

I realize that there is another object type (#Microsoft.OutlookServices.ItemAttachment) for messages and events, but I understand that to mean items that already exist on outlook's servers and are being linked by ID (like attaching a meeting invite for an event that was already created); plus that type doesn't have the ContentBytes as a field for me to populate. For sending on the fly, I would think that any binary file data would be treated the same (these .msg and .eml files are being uploaded from the users' computers and don't necessarily exist on outlook already).

Any idea what's going on here?

---

**Update**
I've tested [creating a draft message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#CreateNewDraft), and [adding the attachments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#Createattachments) in separate posts to the message, then [sending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#SendDraftMessages). Again, same error messages. Creating and sending result in successful status codes. Creating the attachments will result in 500 Internal server errors if the extension is .msg or .eml similarly. The actual email sent will contain all the attachments though.

Comment: I'm investigating this, hope to have more info soon.

Comment: I have the same experience as you. I'll check with our developers and see if I can figure out what's going on here.

Comment: @JasonJohnston Thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! After talking with our developers, I've filed this as a bug with the API. I'll update this answer once I have a resolution, but I don't have a timeline to share at this point.

> **UPDATE:** This has been fixed. You'll now get a `202 Accepted` when you send an attached message. The fix went out some time ago, I've been lax in actually testing it and updating this post! :(

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: If the answer is "it's a bug" with no great workaround, then that seems more like an answer than a comment to me! Is there a public bug tracker I can follow?

Comment: Thanks David. Unfortunately no, the team doesn't use a public bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks for finding time to come back to this!